# Java-SOAP:java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: no further information

Tags: java, xml, soap, java-8, ssl-certificate

I am trying to call a Soap Webservice from my Java application as follows:

```
@Override
    public String getLoginServiciosGeneral() throws Exception {
        String idSesion = "";
        try{
                        
            LoginServiciosGeneralService service = new LoginServiciosGeneralService();
            
            LoginServiciosGeneralPortType port = service.getLoginServiciosGeneral();
            
            idSesion = port.loginServiciosGeneral("prueba");
            System.out.println("hasta aca");
            
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception. Problemas en la llamada al servicio loginServiciosGeneral, motivo: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    return idSesion;
    }
```

Where **LoginServiciosGeneralService** is a class of type *@WebServiceCliente* and **LoginServiciosGeneralPortType** is of *@WebService*

In *Sessionid = port.loginServiciosGeneral("prueba");* the following occurs:

> [24/11/23 7:41:44:298 CET] 000000c4 SystemErr     R javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: no further information
> [24/11/23 7:41:44:299 CET] 000000c4 SystemErr     R   at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.marshaller.impl.alt.MethodMarshallerUtils.createSystemException(MethodMarshallerUtils.java:1363)
> [24/11/23 7:41:44:299 CET] 000000c4 SystemErr     R   at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.marshaller.impl.alt.MethodMarshallerUtils.demarshalFaultResponse(MethodMarshallerUtils.java:1089)
> [24/11/23 7:41:44:299 CET] 000000c4 SystemErr     R   at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.marshaller.impl.alt.DocLitBareMethodMarshaller.demarshalFaultResponse(DocLitBareMethodMarshaller.java:417)
> [24/11/23 7:41:44:299 CET] 000000c4 SystemErr     R   at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.getFaultResponse(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:632)
> [24/11/23 7:41:44:300 CET] 000000c4 SystemErr     R   at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.createResponse(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:566)
> [24/11/23 7:41:44:300 CET] 000000c4 SystemErr     R   at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.invokeSEIMethod(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:432)
> [24/11/23 7:41:44:300 CET] 000000c4 SystemErr     R   at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler.invoke(JAXWSProxyHandler.java:213)
> [24/11/23 7:41:44:301 CET] 000000c4 SystemErr     R   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy138.loginServiciosGeneral(Unknown Source)
> [24/11/23 7:41:44:302 CET] 000000c4 SystemErr     R   at es.seguridadsocial.palexws.descargarmensajes.LoginServiciosGeneralImpl.getLoginServiciosGeneral(LoginServiciosGeneralImpl.java:25)

In the Soap tool I access it without problems, but not in Java. The access URL belongs to a Ministry which contains a signed certificate with its two files: a public one with a .cer extension and a private one with a .p12 extension and its password to access.

I would like to know how to use the certificate in Java to be able to access the URL and have it return data. I would also like to know if the timeout that is returned has to do with Proxy.

These are the input parameters in SOAP:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:ent="https://loginserviciosgeneral.servicio.wslexnet.webservices.lexnet">
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
      <ent:LoginServiciosGeneralIn>
        prueba
      </ent:LoginServiciosGeneralIn>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I use Java version 8, I'm not allowed to use a higher version.

If you need more information, don't hesitate to ask me.

Thank you very much.

soap webservice return data

Comment: Sounds like a proxy issue

Comment: solution for this?

Comment: set the correct proxy entries

Comment: Connection did not complete.  You may have a TLS issue making a connection with HTTPS.  A certificate for TLS may be missing or expired.  The certificate has an encryption mode and old OS may not support the excryption.

Comment: I have two certificates: one public (.cer) and another private (.p12) with its password. How should I use them?